# Cython code doesn't work

Tags: python, function, cython

I wrote some Python code and it worked fine when using the "python". I then converted it to C using "Cython" and used distutils to compile it to a shared library. I then changed some of the code to Cython so it would run faster. But when I imported the .so module and tried to use the command I had "cdef"ed it said that the command didn't exist.
Original code:

```
import time as t
def time(function):
    t1 = t.time()
    function()
    t2 = t.time()
    return t2 - t1
```

New code:

```
import time as t
cdef time(function):
    t1 = t.time()
    function()
    t2 = t.time()
    return t2 - t1
```

I tried using "cdef int time" but I got the same result. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cdef` functions are not exposed to Python. `cpdef` is provided to provide a Python wrapper to a C function defined in Cython.

Also, you're probably better off using [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) than bothering with implementing this.

Comment: I knew there was better ways, but this was just an example.